# Creating variable names from matrix in R

Tags: r

I am new to R, and trying to create a number of new variables in a dataset ("data").

In this dataset, the columns are dichotomous codings of whether or not a question was answered. The question number is represented with a subscript ("Q_1, "Q_2"). Each question has several attributes, which I would like to name using the same subscript (i.e., "Q_Attribute1_1", "Q_Attribute2_1") because I need to reshape the data into long form for multilevel analysis. But because I have 30 questions total, each with 18 question-level attributes, it doesn't seem smart to create 540 variables (30x18) by hand.  An added wrinkle is that each of these associated with a single value such as 0/1.

Having created two vectors--one with the variable names, and one with the associated values--I need to add each of the unique variable names as *columns* to a larger data set ("main.data") with 20,000 cases.  I want the value of this variable to be the same value as that listed in the data above for ALL CASES.  How might this be implemented?

Comment: Why not construct a small test case of 5 Q's, each with 3 (short) attributes? I wonder if `expand.grid(Qs=unique(questions), attribs =unique(Attributes) )` could work .... but you didn't say whether hte attributes were the same for each question.

Comment: So sorry. I'm sure it's my fault! 540 variables--each of which have 1 corresponding value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**CODE THAT RESOLVED MY QUESTION:**

```
You may use "melt" function in reshape2 package to transform the data to 
long format. Hope the following example helps! 
> set.seed(1) 
> data <- matrix(rbinom(15, size = 1, 0.5), 3, 5) 
> colnames(data) <-  paste("attribute", 1 : 5, sep = "") 
> data <- data.frame(question = 1 : 3, data) 
> data

  question attribute1 attribute2 attribute3 attribute4 attribute5 
1        1          0          1          1          0          1 
2        2          0          0          1          0          0 
3        3          1          1          1          0          1 
> library(reshape2) 
> melt(data, "question") 


  question   variable value 
1         1 attribute1     0 
2         2 attribute1     0 
3         3 attribute1     1 
4         1 attribute2     1 
5         2 attribute2     0 
6         3 attribute2     1 
7         1 attribute3     1 
8         2 attribute3     1 
9         3 attribute3     1 
10        1 attribute4     0 
11        2 attribute4     0 
12        3 attribute4     0 
13        1 attribute5     1 
14        2 attribute5     0 
15        3 attribute5     1 `

#Then, concatenate two variables into a unique name.
> data_long$varnames <-paste(data_long$variable, data_long$W1Qs, sep="")  

#Next, create a vector of all of the unique variable names
> myvars <-c(data_long$varnames)
#Also create a vector of the values corresponding to the unique variable names
> myvalues <-c(data_long$value)

#Then, just add in use the vector of var names to create new columns in main dataset
> main.data[myvars] <-0
#Replace the values assigned to those columns FOR ALL ROWS with the values in 2nd vector
> main.data=rep(myvalues, each=NROW(main.data))
```

Answer (score 0):

could you not just place your data in a dataframe:

```
data<-matrix(rbinom(18*30,1,.5),nrow=18,ncol=30)
questions<-paste("Q",1:30,sep="_")
attributes<-paste("Attribute",1:18,sep="")
df<-data.frame(data,row.names=attributes)
names(df)<-questions
```

you can then access all Q_1 answers:

```
> df[,'Q_1']
 [1] 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1
```

all questions with attribute 2:

```
> df['Attribute2',]
           Q_1 Q_2 Q_3 Q_4 Q_5 Q_6 Q_7 Q_8 Q_9 Q_10 Q_11 Q_12 Q_13 Q_14 Q_15
Attribute2   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0    1    1    1    1    1    0
           Q_16 Q_17 Q_18 Q_19 Q_20 Q_21 Q_22 Q_23 Q_24 Q_25 Q_26 Q_27 Q_28
Attribute2    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    0    1    0    0    1    1
           Q_29 Q_30
Attribute2    1    0
```

or the question 1 attribute 18

```
> df['Attribute1','Q_18']
[1] 1
```

EDIT:

if you just want to create 540 variables then:

```
test<-paste("Q_Attribute",c(1:18),sep="")
test<-c(sapply(test,function(x,y){paste(x,y,sep="_")},y=c(1:30)))
lapply(test,function(x){assign(x,NA,envir = .GlobalEnv)})
```

Comment: I apologize; I don't think that I was clear in my description. The questions VARY by attribute, which is why I need to make individual variables for each attribute before shifting to long form.  The larger issue is that these variables for question attributes need to be coded for all respondents to my larger dataset (n=50,000).  I've already constructed the matrix described above...

Comment: Yes! That's awesome. Step 1 complete! The next thing that I need to do, however, is add all 540 of these new variables as columns in my dataset (using 'cbind()'?>). Then, I need to code all respondents as having the value on that variable located in my 30 by 18 matrix. Using your example above, I would (1) bind the new variable name "Attribute2Q_1" to my existing dataset, and then code all respondents as having the value "1" (located at [2,1] or in row 2 column 1).  Does this make sense?  The problem is that I need to code in values for all 540 variables for everyone in my dataset now!